# How to scroll a Gui.Window in Unity3d for Android?

Tags: android, scroll, unity-game-engine

I try scrolling a GUI.Windows with a touch screen on Android, but I can't find anything to do that.

I have the following code:

```
function OnGUI() {
    windowHome = GUI.Window(2, Rect(Screen.width/3,Screen.height/2,(Screen.width/3)*2,Screen.height/4), WindowFunctionHome, " ");
}

function WindowFunctionHome (windowID : int) {
    GUI.BeginScrollView (Rect (10,300,100,100),scrollPosition, Rect (0, 0, 220, 200));  

    for(var i=0;i < ImgSliderProducts.Length;i++)
    {
        GUI.DrawTexture(Rect(20+(i* 100),10,100,100), ImgSliderProducts[i],ScaleMode.ScaleToFit,true);
        GUI.Label(Rect(20+(i* 100),110,100,20),ArabicFixer.Fix(ImgSliderName[i]));
        GUI.Label(Rect(20+(i* 100),130,100,20),ArabicFixer.Fix(ImgSliderFee[i]));
    }

    GUI.EndScrollView ();   
}
```

What do I need to do to enable scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`GUI.BeginScrollView(...)`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUI.BeginScrollView.html) is a static function which returns a `Vector2`. This return value  is the modified scrollPosition. As with most of the immediate mode UI constructs of Unity, that is the value you should feed back into your function call on the next iteration.

So at the very least that should look something like

```
scrollPosition = GUI.BeginScrollView (Rect (10,300,100,100),scrollPosition, Rect (0, 0, 220, 200));
```